# How to provide the -Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml option in nodejs spawn method

Tags: java, node.js

I have angular2-node.js application. I am executing a jar file through the node server.

Jar execution is happening fine but it's using the logback.xml present in the jar file.

Node js code:

```
app.get('/report/:parameter1/:parameter2', function(req, res) {

var fileName = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'javaFile', 'xyz.jar');

spawn('/usr/bin/java', ['-jar ', fileName, parameter1 , parameter2, '&'],{
                                            stdio : ['ignore', out, err],
                            detached : true }).unref();

data = '{response: Success}';
res.status(200).json(data);
res.end();
});
```

I want to refer the different logback.xml file for jar execution while running the jar from UI. So, i tried the below code:

```
spawn('/usr/bin/java', ['-jar -Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml', fileName, cacheName , cacheType, '&'],{
                                            stdio : ['ignore', out, err],
                            detached : true }).unref();
```

But, it also didn't work and throw the below error:

```
Unrecognized option: -jar -Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I am new to node js. I searched the web but couldn't get an answer.

Is there any way to provide the logback.xml file dynamically in node.js code something like we do in shell script like below:

```
nohup java -jar -Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml xyz.jar
```

Can anyone provide any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The args arguments is `<string[]>`, so you should split the multiple args into multiple elements of the array, like you've done for the other arguments. You can check the signature of the method [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Try,

`spawn('/usr/bin/java', ['-jar', '-Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml'], ....`